# Specify which columns are searched via list in-place search box

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, search, list-search-box

We are on SharePoint Online (O365), in a specific list I would like to restrict the in-place list search box to NOT search the Modified By column.  This list has multiple columns that hold individual names and it's possible that a single individual will be listed in all the columns for a specific row.

Using the in-place OOTB search box we'd like to be able to enter an individual name and get ONLY those rows where the name is shown in one of our columns.  Instead what we are getting are any rows where the name is shown AND any rows that have been edited by that name.

In this list only we want to limit the search so that the Modified By column is NOT searched.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter to select needed items. For the columns you want to search, click on the down arrow and select filter to choose the name you are willing to search. It can be done on all your columns.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, we are aware of filters but this list has multiple columns and an individual name might not be in all.  We need a way to search across all columns but not the Modified By column.

Comment: @Ember, per my knowledge, this is not doable for a list search box. A possible approach will be add a customized search box and search result web part. Customize the search query in the result web part

Comment: Thank you @jerry_MSFT, I will look into that option more.  New to SP so learning tricks is based solely on what I can find on forums like this one.